# Parameterized Spock tests and pipe usage

Tags: groovy, spock

I have trouble writing a parameterized test with Spock, when one the parameter needs the pipe character, for instance because its a flag computation.

```
def "verify inferInputType()"() {
        expect:
        inputType == mPresenter.inferInputType(opt)

        where:
        opt                        | inputType
        0                          | 0
        EDITTEXT_TYPE_ALPHANUM     | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
        EDITTEXT_TYPE_NUM          | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
        EDITTEXT_TYPE_FLOAT        | (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)
}
```

The test fails with the following error message :

```
Row in data table has wrong number of elements (3 instead of 2) @ line 25, column 9.
           EDITTEXT_TYPE_FLOAT        | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
           ^
```

The only way I find to make it work is to wrap the parameter inside an closure, like that

```
        EDITTEXT_TYPE_FLOAT        | {InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL}()
```

But it's ugly, if someone has a better solution, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER.or( InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL )
```

Not sure if that is better ;-)